Is there a way to update a specific property of a firewall outbound rule through command prompt?
I wrote a script that would periodically enable/disable an outbound firewall rule to basically allow internet access to a specific app at specific points in time.
Whenever the app itself is allowed internet access (meaning the outbound rule is disabled), it would auto-update if there was a new version available. What I noticed is that after auto-updating, the specific directory where it was located would change, and since firewall rules rely on specific directory locations, this would completely bypass my script and have internet access whenever it needs.
Before auto-updating:

After auto-updating:

My solution was pretty simple; every time that my script runs, it would check the location of the app currently and compare it with the location the last time it was checked. If there was a change in directory location, it would issue a command prompt command to update the firewall rule to match its current location.
Is there a way to update that specific property in the "Programs and Services" section of the properties tab? The images below should help.
An example rule:

The specific rule property in question that I want to update through command prompt:


I have had a lot of success using falahati/WindowsFirewallHelper to programmatically edit Windows Firewall rules in a .NET program.
